# Angular 4 with haml-loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, haml, angular-material2

I am trying to use haml with templates in my Rails 5.1 and Angular 4 project.
I have the haml template working but when I tried to implement Material 2 for Angular, it uses attributes that haml does not add to the DOM.

For example, I am trying to implement a sidenav and I created a component with the following template:

```
-#navbar.component.html.haml
%md-sidenav-container.example-container
  %md-sidenav.example-sidenav{ '#sidenav' => true }
    Jolly good!

  .example-sidenav-content
    %button{'md-button' => true, '(click)' => 'sidenav.open()'}
      Button
```

And here is my component:

```
//navbar.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import navbar from './navbar.html.haml';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  template: navbar
})

export class NavbarComponent {}
```

'#sidvenav' attribute and 'md-button' attribute are not rendered to the DOM.
can I not use haml with Angular 4? should I not use haml with Angular 4? or am I just doing it wrong?

Under config/webpack/loaders I have a file called haml.js

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.html\.haml$/,
  loader: 'haml-haml-loader'
}
```

And under javascript/app I have a file called haml.d.ts

```
declare module "*.haml" {
    const content: string
    export default content
}
```

This is what allows me to use template for haml. There are similar files for html and I render them as strings and they get compiled as needed by html-loader or haml-haml-loader.

Any help would be appreciated.